# Can I set the ObjectId in Backendless manually

Tags: java, android, sqlite, backendless

I use [Parse.com](http://parse.com) for storing my data but since [they will shut down their service](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/) I am going to use [Backendless](http://backendless.com) in the future.

I use it in my Android app for syncing my data between devices. Since the app can work offline I will use a SQLite DB to store the data and sync it to Backendless when online. And new data from Backendless will be stored in the SQLite DB as well to be available when working offline.

So when offline and creating a new record, I have to store it in SQLite until being online again. Now can I set the `ObjectId`, which is the identifier of Backendless objects, manually and will Backendless still get that is has not been saved to the cloud even already having an `ObjectId` set?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the backend accepts an external `objectId` (and I think it doesn't), it's safer to just drop the local `ObjectId` before sending the objects to the backend, and let the backend generate a new one. This way, you won't have to manage several ID generators and worry about unicity.

If you can't change the local `ObjectId`, you can still delete and re-create the local object with the backend Id.